# Search in table without pipe Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to build a search inside a table without using any pipes. This is what I have by now:

.ts

```
  get filteredArray() {
    if (this.searchValue.length === 0) {
      return this.usersList
    }

    return this.usersList.filter((user) => {
      return (this.searchValue.length > 0 ? this.searchValue.indexOf(user.name) !== -1 : true) || 
      (this.searchValue.length > 0 ? this.searchValue.indexOf(user.group) !== -1 : true) || 
      (this.searchValue.length > 0 ? this.searchValue.indexOf(user.age) !== -1 : true)
    })
  }

  inputClick(searchText) {
    if (searchText != "") {
      this.searchValue.push(searchText)
    } else {
      this.searchValue.splice(0, 1)
    }
  }
```

.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (keyup.enter)="inputClick(searchText)">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Group</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Age</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of filteredArray">
      <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.group }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine (if you type something inside `input` and hit ENTER, it will appear, if you delete and hit ENTER, it will revert to the initial array)

As you can see, to do this I filtered through each field of the list:

```
(this.searchValue.length > 0 ? this.searchValue.indexOf(user.name) !== -1 : true) || 
(this.searchValue.length > 0 ? this.searchValue.indexOf(user.group) !== -1 : true) || 
(this.searchValue.length > 0 ? this.searchValue.indexOf(user.age) !== -1 : true)
```

My question is: how can I avoid taking all the fields in my return statement? Because in my database I have more than 30 fields and it's hard work to write 30 different `||`.

Also, how can I modify my code, if I write `joh` instead of `john`, to still find the entry?

Thank you for your time! [Here you can see a working snippet of my project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adw1hf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have work with FormControl in a reactive style, but that is not what you asked for.
I modified your solution to get your user properties, and check wheter your searchText matches a value in one of your user property.

[See this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkipch)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to loop through all fields and check for all fields.

```
containsValue(userObj, searchValue){
    return Object.values(userObj).reduce((prev, cur) => {
        cur = cur.toString();
        return prev || cur.indexOf(searchValue) > -1;
    }, false)
}
```

Use this method in your current function as

```
get filteredArray(){
    ...
    return this.userList.filter((user) => this.containsValue(user, this.searchValue));
}
```

Edit:
If you are not using ES2017, then change Object.values() to Object.keys() and get "cur" value as userObj[cur].
So for pre-es2017:

```
containsValue(userObj, searchValue){
    return Object.keys(userObj).reduce((prev, cur) => {
        let temp = userObj[cur].toString();
        return prev || temp.indexOf(searchValue) > -1;
    }, false);
}
```